# Reading stark overflow csv file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to use scala and spark to read a csv file,the csv file is form stark overflow named valid.csv.
here is the href I download it `https://www.kaggle.com/discussion` part of the csv like this
`Id,Title,Body,Tags,CreationDate,Y
34552974,How to get all the child records from different tables based on given parent ID in sql server,"I am having 4 different tables like
select * from System

select * from Set
select * from Item
select * from Versions

Now for each system Id there will be **n no.of Sets**, and foe **each set** there qill be **n no. of Items** and for **each item** there will be **n no.of Versions**.

**each system has  

n no of set 

each Set has 

n no of Items 

each Item has 

n no of Versions**

So, Now when i give **SystemId** then i have to retrieve all the records from

**Set and Items of each set and Versions of each Items** in single storedprocedure.",,2016-01-01 01:44:52,LQ_EDIT
34554721,Retrieve all except some data of the another table,"I have two table m_master and tbl_appointment
[This is tbl_appointment table][1]

[This is m_master table][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7f7y.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD6Qf.png",,2016-01-01 08:43:50,LQ_EDIT`

my scala version is 2.1 and spark version is 2.1

I try chatgpt,but can't not give me the right code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession}

object StackOverflowDataLoader {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // create spark session
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("StackOverflowDataLoader")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    // read csv file
    val df = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .load("path/to/stackoverflow.csv")

    // show the first 20 rows of the data
    df.show(20)
    
    // stop spark session
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

this is the chatgpt code,and i get the error `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: sorry I put a error herf ,the csv right herf is https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/imoore/60k-stack-overflow-questions-with-quality-rate?resource=download&select=valid.csv